# Importing dictionary variable in another python file

Tags: python, dictionary, import

I have a dictionary with the following contents.

```
dictionary.py

dict = {"xyz":"abc", "qwe":"rty", ..., }
```

I want to import the dict variable into another python file. The restrictions are that I must be able to submit a filepath to the function and get a dictionary in the form of a, well, dictionary. I've tried importlib, but it doesn't take any filepath, but requires the file to be in the same folder as the function. AST imports the dict only when the file looks like such:
`{"xyz":"abc", "qwe":"rty", ..., }`

which means that having the

```
dict =
```

part in the file makes the code break. I'm looking for solutions to get submit a filepath where the code can thereafter go and import/parse the file for the dictionary and import it in the main python file.

I hope I've done justice to the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Why not store it as JSON instead?

Comment: `dict` is a reserved word in Python and I would advise against using it as a variable name.

Comment: When asking for help with your homework you need to show a good faith effort to have solved the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Can you save the dict file locally and read it in any python script you want?

One way would be to use the pickle module:

```
import pickle
# save as a pickle file
with open('data.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(dict,f)

# read pickle file
with open('data.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    dict_ = pickle.load(f)
```

PS: naming your variable as `dict` overrides the python keyword. Better to name it as something else

Edited as per comments:

1. in your main.py or any other script; this will return your dictionary (which was saved locally as a pickle file)

```
import pickle
def read_dict(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        return pickle.load(f)
```

2. You need to save the dictionary only once in your local drive (or until you update the dict again). so you can run this once wherever this dictionary is generated. (If you run that script multiple times the dictionary will be overwritten so can add some checks for that):

```
import pickle
dict_ = {"s":1} # dummy data
file_path = 'data.pkl' # dummy path
with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(dict_,f)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I dont have any data in main.py; the goal is to import the dictionary (it has a different name) into main.py. Doesn't using pickle.dump require me to supplement my dict file with additional data; which I dont have

Comment: I did not understand what this meant: "supplement my dict file with additional data". You can save the dictionary as it is locally and in your main.py you'll just need to read the pickle file and the dictionary will be loaded in.

Comment: basically, there's two files: main.py and dictionary.py. main has a function which is supposed to call dictionary -> extract the dictionary-> return it as a dict. Using pickle.dump requires me to give data to the 'dump' in the dictionary right (that is what i inferred looking at usages online). How would i do that

Comment: edited as per your comments, hopefully that clarifies (as per my understanding)